# Conditional validation in Orbeon Forms

Tags: orbeon

I have an orbeon form which contains 5 fields with `save` and `Send` buttons.

On `save`, only two fields are mandatory and on `send` all 5 fields are mandatory.

How to write validation for this scenario.

**Update:**

I added hidden field with Control Name : `ValidationMode` and my process looks like:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save.*.*">
     xf:setvalue(
        ref   = "bind(ValidationMode-bind)",
        value = "'save'"
    )
    then xf:dispatch(
        name     = "xforms-recalculate",
        targetid = "fr-form-model"
    )
    then validate-all
    then save-final
</property>
```

Still the conditional validation is not working. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `save-draft` button to allow saving without validating. See this [documentation](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/predefined.html). But `save-draft` will entirely skip checking validation before saving.

**Update**

If you want to validate (with "Required" or constraint formulas) depending on the button pressed, I can think of the following way.

Whether a field is required can be expressed by an XPath expression. Somehow that XPath expression would have to depend on the current button pressed, and validation would have to be reapplied at that time. So you could do the following:

- Add a hidden form field, say `validation-mode`, which will contain a value identifying whether the user has pressed one button or the other, say `save` or `send` or blank.
- Make your validations depend on that field (using `$validation-mode`).
- Write a new [process](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/) associated with each of the "Save" or "Send" buttons which:

  - Sets the value of the hidden field, say to `save` or `send`.
  - Forces recalculation/revalidation. There is no built-in action for this yet, but you can do so with the `xf:dispatch(name = "xforms-recalculate", targetid = "fr-form-model")`.
  - Then continues with the process as usual.

So the processes would look like:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save.*.*">
    xf:setvalue(
        ref   = "bind('validation-mode-bind')",
        value = "'save'"
    )
    then xf:dispatch(
        name     = "xforms-recalculate",
        targetid = "fr-form-model"
    )
    then validate-all
    then expand-all
    then save-final
</property>

<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*">
    xf:setvalue(
        ref   = "bind('validation-mode-bind')",
        value = "'send'"
    )
    then xf:dispatch(
        name     = "xforms-recalculate",
        targetid = "fr-form-model"
    )
    then validate-all
    then expand-all
    then send(
        uri     = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php",
        method  = "post",
        content = "xml",
        replace = "all"
    )
</property>
```

Comment: `save-draft` will save the form data even if it isn't valid (No validation will happen here) . But in my case out of 5 fields it is mandate to validate 2 fields on click of  `save-draft`.

Comment: I'm looking for partial validation here.

Comment: I have added hidden field called `ValidationMode` and my processes looks same as above but when I click on these buttons the value is not setting in hidden field(made it as visible to inspect the value) and so conditional validation is not working.

Comment: Did you change, in the process, `validation-mode-bind` to `ValidationMode-bind`? Those names must match.

Comment: Yes, I did, the names are same. Please see my updated question.

Comment: It must be `bind('ValidationMode-bind')` and not just `ValidationMode-bind`.

Comment: Changed to `bind('ValidationMode-bind')`, Still no luck. Any other configuration to look for?